# what are the deployment scenarios for L2TP tunnel, GRE tunnel and MPLS Tunnel (l2vpn vpws)

Tags: vpn

what are the deployment scenarios for  L2TP tunnel, GRE tunnel and MPLS Tunnel (l2vpn vpws)

Answer (score 7):

I'm reluctant to answer this question because there are exceptions to just about any scenario.  But here goes anyway.  Generally speaking:

**MPLS** is commonly used when you want to isolate the data paths over a shared network infrastructure.  MPLS allows for separate routing/forwarding for each isolated path. The most common scenario is a carrier offering private WAN connectivity to its customers.

**L2TP** is an older technology that's rapidly becoming obsolete.  It is (was) used to provide layer 2 connectivity over a layer 3 network.  VXLAN is probably the best replacement.

**GRE**, as the name implies, is a generic tunnel that can be used for L2 and L3 routing over a L3 network. A common use case is routing between sites when you don't have control over the intermediate network.